# DateTimePicker only for current Month

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker, monthcalendar

I have a `DateTimePicker` in a Form. I need to restrict the user to only select a Date from the current Month: for example, from `1 November 2018`  to `30 November 2018`.

I tried these lines of code:

```
DtpIssue.MinDate = New Date Time(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
DtpIssue.MaxDate = New Date Time(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
```

But it shows only the current date: `10 November 2018`.
What should I do to fix the current Month for the `DateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last day of the month is returned by [DateTime.DaysInMonth()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth), passing the current Year and Month.

```
Dim FirstOfMonth As Date = New DateTime(Date.Now.Year, Date.Now.Month, 1)
Dim EndOfMonth As Date = 
    New DateTime(Date.Now.Year, Date.Now.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(Date.Now.Year, Date.Now.Month))
```

In a similar format, applied to your controls:

```
DtpIssue.MinDate = New Date(Today.Year, Today.Month, 1)
DtpIssue.MaxDate = New Date(Today.Year, Today.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(Today.Year, Today.Month))
```